# Exporting jetty server project

Tags: java, jetty

I have created a dynamic web project in Eclipse for Java EE. Then I installed the Eclipse jetty plugin (http://eclipse-jetty.sourceforge.net/), created a Run-Configuration and it showed the index.html in the WebContent-folder. That's what I wanted!
Now I have added the jetty-all.jar and the servlet-api.jar to the build-path and a simple Servlet to the project called Hello.java looking like this:

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
        writer.println("<body>");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) writer.println(String.valueOf(i));
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("</html>");  
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

and a web.xml inside the WEB-INF of the WebContent-folder looking like this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebServer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now when i open `localhost:8080/hello` it shows the numbers from 1 to 100. Everything is fine.
But now I've been looking for hours how to export the project, so someone else can start something like a .jar and a server starts like it did for me. Is this easy possible using the plugin, or what do I have to do?

Comment: So to be clear, you're wanting to pack up Jetty and your `war` into a single `jar` that can be run standalone?

Comment: @chrylis yes, I want to be able to have Jetty running with my servlet just by executing a single jar

Comment: Might be overkill, but my first approach would be to use Spring Boot. I'm usually using Spring MVC anyway, but you *can* just deploy arbitrary servlets if you want.

Comment: @chrylis thank you for the suggestion. My problem ist, that the software is for a commercial purpose, and gopivotal, forbids that...

Comment: What are you talking about? Nearly everything in Spring is Apache licensed.

Comment: @chrylis where did you see that?

Comment: **Everywhere**. I really have no idea where you got the idea that you can't use Spring for commercial projects, and I'd be interested in any sort of reference you have.

Comment: @chrylis well, I've scrolled down to "Terms of Use" and looked for the "Use of software". There I've seen "You may not use evaluation Software for commercial, development or production purposes." After reading it again, I guess you're right as I have skipped the word "evaluation". But I still haven't found anything else about licenses...

Comment: Check any of the code. I think what you're looking at is tc Server and perhaps a few other "enterprise" components like GemFire.